# Get XML doc sent

Tags: c#, xml, http-post

I've got 2 projects -- 1 is purely just a .ashx generic handler, and the other is a test project that posts an XML doc to it.  How do I get the XML doc that was posted?

The client code is (shortened for brevity)

```
    string xmlToSend = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><APPLICATION>  <TRANSACTIONTYPE>12</TRANSACTIONTYPE></APPLICATION>";
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:8022/handle.ashx"));
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlToSend);
    Stream os = null;
    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    os.Close();
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    //if (webResponse == null)
    //{ return null; }
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string sRet = "";
    sRet = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

The receiving code is

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // Well, not sure what to do here.  
    // context.Request.Params has a count of 48, but doesn't have the XML.
    // context.Request.Form has a count of 0

}
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental here.  But I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Please don't suggest to use WCF unless that's the only way I'm going to get this to work.  I find WCF very difficult and finicky to get up and going.

I can't even get my handler to break on my breakpoints, but I know that it is being called (I've changed it multiple times to return the date, date and time, some gibberish strings I type in, so I know it is being called and can respond back.)

Comment: Just wanting to point out that WebRequest.Create should contain an uri to a resource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx

Comment: Done, Joe.  Although I feel like I cheated since I just used "new Uri" and passed my url to it as the constructor.  Not sure what it got me, but hey, it's done.

Comment: @Matt: that's not a valid URI. I'm sure that code will immediately throw an exception.

Comment: Yes you need to fix your uri which is pretty much the url you will sending your xml to. "http://yourserver.com/xmlhandler.ashx" <The comments stripped the http:// off> for example. I also posted an answer to your question about the ProcessRequest part.

Comment: Sorry --that was a copy and paste error.  The original string was supposed to be "http://localhost:8022" -- the XML was passed as the 2nd argument and used in the line "byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);"  I screwed this all up by trying to shrink the code.

Comment: I edited the question to be code that actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`context.Request.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) contains the data you are looking for.

Microsoft's example:

```
System.IO.Stream str; String strmContents;
Int32 counter, strLen, strRead;
// Create a Stream object.
str = Request.InputStream;
// Find number of bytes in stream.
strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
// Create a byte array.
byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
// Read stream into byte array.
strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);

// Convert byte array to a text string.
strmContents = "";
for (counter = 0; counter < strLen; counter++)
{
    strmContents = strmContents + strArr[counter].ToString();            
}
```

There are other better ways when working with text such as [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) or concatenation using [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the answer.  I shortened it (per your suggestion really) to this:  
            System.IO.Stream input; 
            String contents;
            input = context.Request.InputStream;
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
            contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   string data = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.